# How to render response from second request on material-table in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I am using material-table with reactjs to create a data grid.
I am filling the table with data from a previous HTTP request from an API and want to render the response of a second HTTP request in another column of that same table

`render: rowData => this.Myfunction(rowData)`

```
Myfunction(data){
  axios.post('/api/status', {
      payload:data
    })
    .then( res => {
        if(res.data[0] != undefined){
       return res.data[0].status
      }
      else{
          return 'Null'
      }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
     });
   }
}
```

The data I send to myFunction works properly for each row, but I cannot return the response I get from my request with axios.

I also tried

```
return axios.post('/api/reviews', {
  payload:data
})
```

But I get an error:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you     meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is you are using [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) in `MyFunction` but not returning it correctly. The following will set the value of `output` to `undefined`, because the return inside `then` is asynchronous.

```
function Component() {
  const data = {};
  const [output, setOutput] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    setOutput(MyFunction(data));
  }, []);

  return <div>{ JSON.stringify(output) }</div>;
}
```

First, you need to return the promise from `MyFunction`.

```
function Myfunction(data) {
  return axios
    .post('/api/status', {
      payload: data
    })
    .then(res => {
      if (res.data[0] != undefined) {
        return res.data[0].status;
      } else {
        return 'Null';
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Then handle the result of the promise using a `then` call.

```
function Component() {
  const [output, setOutput] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    MyFunction(data).then(setOutput);
  }, []);

  return (
      <div>{ JSON.stringify(output) }</div>
  )
}
```